# Memory Caching in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, memorycache

I have written one Caching class but i am confused how do i use it in application in MVC ?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.Caching;


namespace ABC
{

    public class InMemoryCache : ICache
    {
        protected ObjectCache Cache
        {
            get
            {
                return MemoryCache.Default;
            }
        }
        /// Insert value into the cache using key, Value pairs 

        public void Add<T>(T o, string key)
        {
            if (o == null)
                return;

            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheExpirationTime"]));
            Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, o), policy);
        }

        public void Update<T>(T o, string key)
        {
            if (Cache.Contains(key))
            {
                Cache[key] = o;
            }
            else
            {
                Add(o, key);
            }
        }


        /// Remove item from cache

        public void Remove(string key)
        {
            Cache.Remove(key);
        }


        /// Check for item in cache        
        public bool Exists(string key)
        {
            return Cache[key] != null;
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            foreach (var item in Cache)
                Remove(item.Key);
        }

        /// Retrieve cached item.Default(T) if item doesn't exist   
        public bool Get<T>(string key, out T value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Exists(key))
                {
                    value = default(T);
                    return false;
                }

                value = (T)Cache[key];
            }
            catch
            {
                value = default(T);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Cache[key];
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

I have BaseController where i have written OnAuthentication()

```
//How can i use Caching here as it hits on every click made in application
protected override void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
{
            Check.NotEmpty(SsoId, "Unable to determine your AmexWeb logon identity. Please contact the system administrator.");

            var requestingUser = new RBACUser(SsoId, _sprocService);
//How can i use Caching here as it hits on every click made in application
            UserPermissions = requestingUser.UserPermissions;
            PermissionsMaster = requestingUser.PermissionsMaster;
            var user = LoggedInUser = requestingUser.User;

            if (user == null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Session != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session["User"] = null;
                    HttpContext.Session["UserName"] = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (HttpContext.Session != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session["User"] = user.ADSId;
                    HttpContext.Session["UserName"] = user.FullName;
                }
                _userId = user.UserId;
                _regionCode = user.Segment.RegionCode;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement caching in OnActionExecuting() method so it would work only once per action.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Work with a cache here           

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```